# Java Reflection error trying to convert Field into WebElement

Tags: java, reflection, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm struggling with i believe is a reflection problem.

Here is the thing,
On my automation project I'm trying to create a helper class to validate Page Labels from my web application, to that i create a @annotation which contain just a label field.

It looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface ExpectedLabel{
    String label() default "";
}
```

At my Page Class i have the field:

```
@ExpectedLabel(label="Faça seu Login")
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[@id='login']/form/h3")
private WebElement facaSeuLoginLabel;
```

And here is my helper class method to validate labels:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public boolean validateLabels(Class validationClass){
    for (Field field: validationClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(field.getType() ==  WebElement.class && field.isAnnotationPresent(ExpectedLabel.class)){
            field.setAccessible(true);
            ExpectedLabel expectedLabel = field.getAnnotation(ExpectedLabel.class);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(expectedLabel.label())){
                try {
                    WebElement element = (WebElement) field.get(WebElement.class);
                    if(!StringUtils.equals(element.getText(), expectedLabel.label())){
                        LoggerUtil.warn("O campo "+field.getName()+" da Page "+validationClass.getSimpleName()+" tem um label invalido! Esperado : ("+expectedLabel.label()+") Obtido: ("+element.getText()+")!", validationClass.getSimpleName());
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is, i have to call WebElement.getText() to have acess to the Real Page label and then compare to that one in the annotation @ExpectedLabel.label.
Whatever I tried, just cant convert field into WebElement.

I already tried to create an implementation of WebElement called WebElementImpl and done the conversion, but still doesn't worked. 
Other approach that doesn't worked was trying to call the getText() method directly from Field, getting his public methods, but i don't think that is possible.

Here is the exception i get when tried to convert the objects:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.openqa.selenium.WebElement field com.org.pages.LoginPage.facaSeuLoginLabel to java.lang.Class
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at com.org.helpers.LabelValidatorUtil.validateLabels(LabelValidatorUtil.java:20)
    at com.org.telas.LoginPageTest.loginPageValidationTest(LoginPageTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
```

*Obs: WebElement is an interface, so how can i make the conversion?
New approaches to solve the problem are welcome.*

Comment: I don't get what you are doing, `Field.get` is meant to get the value of a field of a specific instance but you are using it as `field.get(WebElement.class)`, while it should be `field.get(object)`.

Comment: Where is this method running? Do you have a reference to the page that contains the field? I suspect `field.get(WebElement.class)` wants to be `field.get(this)` or `field.get(page)` or something similar. If you want to get the value of an instance field, you've got to have an instance to work with...

Comment: You are right @Jack and Jon , i need to pass an instance of my Page to the Field.get(page) method. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the wrong object on which the field is to be read. As per this line:

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) field.get(WebElement.class);
```

The object being passed to field.get() is of the type java.lang.Class, so you're literally requesting something like `java.lang.Class.fieldName`, with "fieldName" being whatever the name of the field in the current iteration is.

What is missing in your question is the object from which to read the field in question. **This must be the object that you're validating**. You should obtain it in the validate method, or, better, receive just the object:

```
    public boolean validateLabels(Object object) {
        Class<?> validationClass = object.getClass();

        for (Field field: validationClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(field.getType() ==  WebElement.class && field.isAnnotationPresent(ExpectedLabel.class)){
                field.setAccessible(true);
                ExpectedLabel expectedLabel = field.getAnnotation(ExpectedLabel.class);
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(expectedLabel.label())){
                    try {
                        WebElement element = (WebElement) field.get(object);
                        if(!StringUtils.equals(element.getText(), expectedLabel.label())){
                            LoggerUtil.warn("O campo "+field.getName()+" da Page "+validationClass.getSimpleName()+" tem um label invalido! Esperado : ("+expectedLabel.label()+") Obtido: ("+element.getText()+")!", validationClass.getSimpleName());
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The method is now receiving the object with values to be validated, then inferring the class from it.
As mentioned above, the most important change is here: `field.get(object)`

Check get's java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: That worked man, thanks for your answer. Now it makes more sense what i am doing.